# Populate Array in Controller Codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I want to populate array record in controller, what should I do?

```
$data['list'] = $this->tshirt_model->getAllModelType(0,0,1); //this working
foreach($data['list']->result_array() as $row) :

$info =array('name'=>$row['name']);

endforeach;

print_r($info); die(); //when i tracing, only returned last record. it should be 20 records.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will be the last record because $info is just array as I can see.

Try using:

```
$info[] =array('name'=>$row['name']);
```

in some versions of php you shoud use:

```
foreach($data['list']->result_array() as $key => $row) :

$info[$key] =array('name'=>$row['name']);

endforeach;
```

Comment: The alternative syntax is not preferred if it has no clean html in it.